# Getting this error: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I am trying to write this program to calculate the perimeter of a 2d list (treating it like a rectangle basically) and I keep getting this error. I also need some help on figuring out how to sum the columns of the 'rectangle' without adding the corners twice. Thank you for your help in advance

```
def perimeter_sum(arr2d):
    col_sum=0
    first_row=arr2d[0]
    last_row=arr2d[-1]
    for i in range(len(arr2d)):
        col_sum=arr2d[1+i][0]+arr2d[1+i][-1]
        sum = first_row + last_row+col_sum
    return sum
a2d = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,9],[9, 0, 1,2]] #error occurred here
perimeter_sum(a2d)
```

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Comment: The error is almost certainly coming from `sum = first_row + last_row+col_sum`. `first_row` and `last_row` are lists, `col_sum` is a number. What are you expecting that addition to return?

Comment: `arr2d[1+i]` will get an error on the last iteration of the `for` loop. Why are you adding 1?

Comment: oh I see sorry I am still learning

Comment: `first_row` and `last_row` are both lists, while `col_sum` is a number.  When applied to two lists, the "+" operator concatenates them into a new, longer list, so `first_row + last_row` is a list.  Attempting to add `col_sum` to that list then produces an error, since you cannot apply the `+` operator to a list and a number.

Comment: do you just want to get the sum of each list? or the sum of the sums of each list?

Answer (score 0):

So the error you're getting is because you're trying to add the rows (first_row and last_row) to a scalar int value (col_sum), hence the cannot add concatenate list not int.

To get the perimeter of the 2D array you can sum the last and first row, and the last and first columns as you were trying, and then subtract the corners at the end unless there is a specific reason you can't do that. Something like:

```
def perimeter_sum(arr2d):
    first_row = sum(arr2d[0])
    last_row = sum(arr2d[-1])
    first_col = sum([arr2d[i][0] for i in range(len(arr2d))])
    last_col = sum([arr2d[i][-1] for i in range(len(arr2d))])
    
    # sum with double counted corners
    s = sum([first_row, last_row, first_col, last_col])
    
    # decrement once for each corner
    return (s - arr2d[0][0] - arr2d[0][-1] - arr2d[-1][0] - arr2d[-1][-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()` to get the total of a list. Use this to sum the first and last rows. Then loop through the intermediate rows and add in the first and last elements.

```
def perimiter_sum(arr2d):
    sum = sum(arr2d[0]) + sum(arr2d[-1])
    for row in arr2d[1:-2]:
        sum += row[0] + row[-1]
    return sum
```

The loop doesn't include the first and last rows, so you won't include the corners twice.